# svg animateMotion is offset from path

Tags: html, css, svg

I have this svg:
[image: circle with box]

My goal is to make the box move along the path while keeping its rotation. To make that happen I added an `<animateMotion />` element to the square with the same path as the circle. (demo [here](https://codepen.io/jescowuester/pen/GRRNxoO?editors=1000)). The path of both the circle and the animateMotion starts with `M` which as far as I know signals an absolute position within the SVG. For some reason, though the square is rotated by 90deg and is moving way outside of the circle (while still following a circular path).

```html
<svg width="133" height="131" viewBox="0 0 266 131"  fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="M102.242 63.2475C102.242 43.3399 86.105 27.202 66.197 27.202C46.2889 27.202 30.151 43.3399 30.151 63.2475C30.151 83.154 46.2889 99.2939 66.1965 99.2939C86.105 99.2939 102.243 83.154 102.243 63.248" stroke="#00F" stroke-width="1"/>
  
  <path d="M95.0596 24.2323L79.2727 43.3838L73.0606 38.2323L88.8177 19.0823L95.0601 24.2333" fill="red">
      <animateMotion
    path="M102.242 63.2475C102.242 43.3399 86.105 27.202 66.197 27.202C46.2889 27.202 30.151 43.3399 30.151 63.2475C30.151 83.154 46.2889 99.2939 66.1965 99.2939C86.105 99.2939 102.243 83.154 102.243 63.248"
    rotate="auto"
    dur="6s" repeatCount="indefinite" fill="freeze"/>
  </path>
</svg>
```

How can I make it work and why is it not working?

Comment: Animate motion is an additional transform to the path and the path being transformed is not at the origin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to adjust the path of the object you will rotate to make it the closest possible to the `(0,0)` point (origin) of your SVG to avoid the translation effect.

Here is an approximation where the object is following the path. Still not perfect so I applied a rotation to correct the final position. I also considered the use of `<mpath />` to avoid repeatig the same path twice:

```css
svg {
  border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<svg width="133" height="131" viewBox="0 0 133 131"  fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="M102.242 63.2475C102.242 43.3399 86.105 27.202 66.197 27.202C46.2889 27.202 30.151 43.3399 30.151 63.2475C30.151 83.154 46.2889 99.2939 66.1965 99.2939C86.105 99.2939 102.243 83.154 102.243 63.248" stroke="#00F" stroke-width="1" id="path"/>
  
  <path d="M21.0596 -13.7677 L5.2727 5.3838 L-0.9394 0.2323 L14.8177 -18.9177 L21.0601 -13.7667" fill="red" transform="rotate(-50,10,20)">
     <animateMotion 
    dur="6s" repeatCount="indefinite" fill="freeze" rotate="auto-reverse">
      <mpath xlink:href="#path"/>
    </animateMotion>
  </path>
</svg>
```

And since it's a rectangle you can simplify like below:

```css
svg {
  border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<svg width="133" height="131" viewBox="0 0 133 131"  fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="M102.242 63.2475C102.242 43.3399 86.105 27.202 66.197 27.202C46.2889 27.202 30.151 43.3399 30.151 63.2475C30.151 83.154 46.2889 99.2939 66.1965 99.2939C86.105 99.2939 102.243 83.154 102.243 63.248" stroke="#00F" stroke-width="1" id="path"/>
  

  <rect x="-5" y="-15" width="10" height="30" fill="red" >
     <animateMotion 
    dur="6s" repeatCount="indefinite" fill="freeze" rotate="auto">
      <mpath xlink:href="#path"/>
    </animateMotion>
  </rect>
</svg>
```

Comment: thanks! Is there any way I could perform that transformation you did in step 1 programmatically? I usually get just the svg and then my app needs to add the movement.

Comment: @cubefox you can always apply a translation to put the element back to origin like this:https://jsfiddle.net/gstencp5/1/

Comment: @TemaniAfif Its working for rectangle but not for path, i have a very complex shape